# Do I need an Android Emulator for Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator, emulation

I'm just beginning development with Flutter and I work on my Macbook Air.
I already have the iOS emulator on my laptop. So my question is do I necessarily need the android emulator to continue developing with flutter or can I manage with the iOS emulator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want to prototype it is feasible to only use the IOS Simulator for production apps I highly recommend real devices.

Either way, you do not need an android emulator. Just start the IOS Simulator check if your device is there with `flutter devices` and execute `flutter run` to start the application.

Answer (score 1):

You do not, But you must have Android studio (and Xcode) or flutter doctor will give you errors.

Comment: But I have errors from flutter doctor even now but I can still run code (These errors come for a different reason)